# The growth of the commutative polynomial algebra $\mathbb K[x_1,\ldots,x_d]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I cannot understand why the growth of the commutative polynomial algebra $\mathbb K[x_1,\ldots,x_d]$ is polynomial of degree $d$; i.e. is $P_d$ and has a polynomial growth?

I will appreciate if someone can explain it to me.

Thanks!

> > For a finitely generated algebra $A$, let $V$ be its finite-dimensional generating subspace. Then $A=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n$ for $A_n=\mathbb K+V+\dots+V^n$. Let the function $d_V(n)=\dim_{\mathbb K}(A_n)$. Then the growth of $A$, i.e. $\mathcal G(A)$ will be defind as $\mathcal G(A):=\mathcal G(d_V)$.

Comment: What do you call the *growth* of a polynomial algebra?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! I edited the post and I explained what I could understand!

Answer (score 0):

$A_n$ is the dimension of $K+V+\cdots+V^n$ which is the number of monomials
$x_1^{t_1}\cdots x_d^{t_d}$ with $t_1+\cdots+t_n\le d$.
This is the number of $d$-tuples of nonnegative integers $(t_1,\ldots,t_d)$ with sum
$\le n$. That is the number of $(d+1)$-tuples of nonnegative integers $(t_1,\ldots,t_d,t_{d+1})$ with sum $n$ (setting $t_{d+1}=n-t_1-\cdots-t_d$).
This number is $\binom{n+d}d$ by the
"[stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))" argument. Then for fixed $d$
$$\binom{n+d}d=\frac1{d!}n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-d+1)$$
is a polynomial of degree $d$ in $n$.